# Stuck outgoing email in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I use Outlook 2010 with Outlook Connector, in which my two other Hotmail accounts have been sending and receiving properly and fine for the past year.

**In Outlook:** I tried to add a third Hotmail account today, but it only receives, and fails to send, any email. From this account, all emails remain stuck in the Outbox folder and generate this error message:

> Task 'Sending - ...@outlook.com' reported error (0x8DE0006): The operation failed

I tried to Google this problem but there were overly too many results, none of which help.

**Yet on hotmail.com:** This 3rd email account functions completely normally.

**User  jjk_charles's comment:** How do I "configure the problematic mail account alone" there?

**User root's comment:** How do I determine 'What Account Type is your Outlook profile?'

I use Outlook Connector, so didn't manually 'Outgoing mail server'. It functions normally for my other 2 Hotmails. 'Test Account Settings' reveals no errors.

Comment: Does this happen with all the email sent from this account or just some?

Comment: @James Thank you. Yes, all. I just updated my OP.

Comment: Can you try creating a new Outlook Profile (Control Panel->Mail->Profiles) and configure the problematic mail account alone on that one?

Comment: What Account Type is your Outlook profile? Is your Outgoing mail server configured correctly? What are the results when you attempt to Test Account Settings?

Comment: @jjk_charles Thanks. Please see my updated OP above?

Comment: @root Thanks. Please see my updated OP above?

Comment: @LePressentiment Posted the steps as an answer, try and let us know if it helps.

Comment: My Outlook is 2007, but the process should be the same to run a test. Tools -> Account Settings -> Select your account and click Change. From here you can see the Account Type, incoming/outgoing mail servers, and Test Account Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new Outlook Profile (Control Panel->Mail->Profiles) and configure the problematic mail account alone on that profile. Steps to do the same are as follows:

- **Open *Mail Setup* Window** (Control Panel->Mail)
  [image: Mail Setup Window]
- **Open Profiles** (***Show Profiles*** button)

[image: Mail Profiles]

- Create a new profile (When prompted, enter the details relevant to problematic account)
- Once new profile is created, make sure to choose "Prompt for a profile to be used". This will make sure you are prompted each time as to which profile will be used.

[image: New Profile Created]

Once the above steps are completed, try to run Outlook and choose the new profile that has been created. See if the account is able to send/receive without any issues.